# How to enable the window.status in a popup?

Tags: javascript, popup, statusbar

I'm using

```
window.status = "myStatusText"
```

And it's working fine in a normal window in my application, but if I want to use this function in a normal old-fashioned popup-window, it is not working.

The statusbar of the popup is visible. I can see the original URLs of the hyperlinks in the statusbar and i want to hide them.

Is this normal, that window.status does not override the original text in a popup?

```
<span id="mySpan" class="mySpanClass">

<a id="myLink" href="javascript:myClickFunction();" onmouseover="window.status='myWindowStatus';" onmouseout="window.status='';" >Link</a>

</span>
```

I've removed the onmouseout event and now the onmouseover-text is visible, AFTER the mouse was pointing the link!

Comment: Open the popup with status=yes and it will work.

Comment: I should mention, that the statusbar is visible. I see the original URLs of the hyperlinks and i want to hide them.

Comment: added the code of the hyperlink. Maybe <span> is evil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that we need to cancel the inbuilt browser handling of the event. This is simple to do:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="window.status = 'test'; return true;" onmouseout="window.status = ''; return true;">Text</a>
```

You probably are, but are you supplying status=1 in the window.open method?

For example:

```
window.open ("http://www.stackoverflow.com","mywindow","status=1");
```

Some browsers, for example IE, only show the status bar in a popup window if the site isn't trusted, so, for example, on an intranet site, unless you specifically add status=1, it wont show the status bar.

If you can see the status bar, are you getting a particular error or is it just not working at all?

Can you set the text of the status bar from some script inside the popup window?

Comment: I can see the original link-text. If I hover a hyperlink, then the statusbar says e.g. "javascript:myClickFunction();". (I want to override this, that the result is "Click here!" instead of  "javascript:myClickFunction();".

Comment: I must add, however, that on an internet site, I probably wouldn't do this. In an age where people are becoming increasingly more aware of malicious websites, not being able to see where/what a link is going to do makes it more untrustworthy. IMO of course.

Comment: not working yet. if add the mouseover to the span it's working, but not in the <a> tag and this is what i want.

Comment: See updated answer - basically, add return true; after the window.status.

Comment: I've removed the onmouseout event and now the onmouseover-text is visible, AFTER the mouse was pointing the link! With and without "return: true;" Also i want to mention, that i have no website, but a bigger application. So i know what you mean and i agree for websites.

Comment: I left 'test' in my onmouseout event - sorry, I've edited - this now resets onmouseout too. I resisted the urge to change the window.status text to "Click here for a free iPod" ;-)

Comment: Summary:
I add only the onmouseover event to the link and it works after the mouse has left the link (but actually not when the mouse is over the link).
I add onmouseout and nothing happens (the original href-link is visible).
It works correctly in every "normal" (not popup) window. :\

Comment: Browser development :-) Thanks for the interesting question!

Answer (score 2):

Open the popup with status=yes and it will work. – (check [window.open documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open))

Answer (score 2):

Open the popup window this way

window.open ("you url", "mywindow","status=1,toolbar=1");